# Unable to send Wrapper class as a return type in @invocableMethod

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow, wrapper-class

[image]We created a wrapper class and calling from SS_NBA_APIResponse class. Here i am getting an error that i can't send wrapper class as a return type. will you please help me how to send the wrapper data to the flow.

```
public class SS_NBA_ApexWrapper {
  public class NbaMessages {
        public String uuid;
        public String priority;
        public String nbaName;
        public String nbaMessage;
        public String creationDate;
        public String csrNotes;
        public String subChannel;
        public List<AdditionalProperties> additionalProperties;
    }

    public class Member_id {
        public String idSource;
        public String idValue;
        public String idType;
    }

    public class NbaResult {
        public Member_id member_id;
        public String srcMemberId;
        public List<NbaMessages> nbaMessages;
    }

    public class SS_NBA_ApexWrapperCls {
        public ReadMemberNextBestActionsResponse readMemberNextBestActionsResponse;
    }

    public class AdditionalProperties {
        @InvocableVariable
        public String key;
         @InvocableVariable
        public String value;
    }

    public class ReadMemberNextBestActionsResponse {
        public String channel;
        public String responseCode;
        public List<NbaResult> nbaResult;
    }
 
    public static SS_NBA_ApexWrapper parse(String json) {
        return (SS_NBA_ApexWrapper) System.JSON.deserialize(json, SS_NBA_ApexWrapper.class);
    }

}
```

---

```
public class SS_NBA_APIResponse {
   @InvocableMethod(Label='Next Best Action')
   public static list<SS_NBA_ApexWrapper> fetchNBAResult(){
        String jsonResp;
        list<SS_NBA_ApexWrapper> apexWrapper = new list<SS_NBA_ApexWrapper>();
        
        SS_NBA_CustomMetadata__mdt[] nbaMetadata = [select id, MasterLabel, NBA_JSON_Response__c, NBA_Type__c
                                                from SS_NBA_CustomMetadata__mdt
                                                where nba_type__c = 'Single NBA'];
        system.debug('nbaMetadata: '+nbaMetadata);

        for(SS_NBA_CustomMetadata__mdt record: nbaMetadata) {
           jsonResp = record.NBA_JSON_Response__c;
        }
        SS_NBA_ApexWrapper myClass = SS_NBA_ApexWrapper.parse(jsonResp);
        
        apexWrapper.add(myClass);
        
        return apexWrapper;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Can you screenshot the exact error?

Comment: where is the error? Can you add screenshot to the question Lakshmi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure all variables you need are declared with @innvocable annotated.

And as per the docs [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm)

> Make sure that your class contains at least one member variable with the invocable variable annotation.

Hence your apex class should expose at least one variable, I modified your apex class to below,

```
public class SS_NBA_APIResponse {
   @InvocableMethod(Label='Next Best Action')
   public static list<Response> fetchNBAResult(){
    String jsonResp;
    list<Response> apexWrapper = new list<Response>();
    
    SS_NBA_CustomMetadata__mdt[] nbaMetadata = [select id, MasterLabel, NBA_JSON_Response__c, NBA_Type__c
                                            from SS_NBA_CustomMetadata__mdt
                                            where nba_type__c = 'Single NBA'];
    system.debug('nbaMetadata: '+nbaMetadata);

    for(SS_NBA_CustomMetadata__mdt record: nbaMetadata) {
       jsonResp = record.NBA_JSON_Response__c;
    }
    SS_NBA_ApexWrapper myClass = SS_NBA_ApexWrapper.parse(jsonResp);
    Response response = new Response();
    response.result = myClass;
    
    apexWrapper.add(response);
    
    return apexWrapper;
} 

public class Response {
   
    @InvocableVariable
    public SS_NBA_ApexWrapper result;

    }  
 }
```

Comment: Hi Mohit,  I am getting the following error now - Illegal assignment from SS_NBA_ApexWrapper to List<SS_NBA_ApexWrapper> at this line -  response.result = myClass;

Comment: Just fixed a typo! Trailhead is a best resource to skill up